# Community response for: passing stuffs between two forms

Tags: discussion

There is a lot of questions on how to pass this or that from one form to the other.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263099/pass-object-between-forms-c-sharp), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087934/passing-data-between-two-forms-using-properties), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088213/passing-data-between-two-forms-using-properties), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117578/pass-data-between-forms-for-a-selected-row-in-datagridview), ...

And I see new ones multiples times in a week. [Some are obvious duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431234/forms-not-communicating-correctly), but are still open.

Those questions are obviously asked by peoples who are new to programming and SO resulting in poorly written questions.

The (accepted!) responses are also not always good. Mostly poor design, where we give the first form as a parameter for the second one, it's go against KISS, [separation of presentation and content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content), ...

I think we need an official response for those questions and close all the duplicates.